# Unable to retrieve specific users foreign key, then output that foreign key row into data grid

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, wpf

I have a `users` table in my database which has a foreign key for `Packages` (`PackageId`), I want a query in which I can retrieve the specific package details for that one user. 
So in theory I need to retrieve that users `PackageId` from the table then output that particular package into my Data grid. Another issue is that I need to verify which user is logged into the application as well to specify which users package details will be output in the grid.

Here is my working log in query which only takes email as verification.

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
            con.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Connection"].ConnectionString;

            try
            {
                con.Open();
                string query = "SELECT COUNT(1) from AspNetUsers WHERE Email=@Email";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", txtUsername.Text);

                int count = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
                if (count == 1)
                {

                    MainWindow mainWindow = new MainWindow();
                    mainWindow.Show();
                    this.Close();

                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Incorrect Login Information");
                }

            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
```

Here is my users table Code:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AspNetUsers] (
    [Id]                   NVARCHAR (450)     NOT NULL,
    [APIKey]               UNIQUEIDENTIFIER   NULL,
    [AccessFailedCount]    INT                NOT NULL,
    [AccountType]          NVARCHAR (MAX)     NULL,
    [ConcurrencyStamp]     NVARCHAR (MAX)     NULL,
    [Email]                NVARCHAR (256)     NULL,
    [EmailConfirmed]       BIT                NOT NULL,
    [FirstName]            NVARCHAR (MAX)     NULL,
    [LastName]             NVARCHAR (MAX)     NULL,
    [Locations]            INT                NOT NULL,
    [LockoutEnabled]       BIT                NOT NULL,
    [LockoutEnd]           DATETIMEOFFSET (7) NULL,
    [NormalizedEmail]      NVARCHAR (256)     NULL,
    [NormalizedUserName]   NVARCHAR (256)     NULL,
    [PackageId]            INT                NULL,
    [PasswordHash]         NVARCHAR (MAX)     NULL,
    [PeriodOrderQty]       INT                NULL,
    [PhoneNumber]          NVARCHAR (MAX)     NULL,
    [PhoneNumberConfirmed] BIT                NOT NULL,
    [Qualifications]       INT                NOT NULL,
    [SecurityStamp]        NVARCHAR (MAX)     NULL,
    [TotalOrderQty]        INT                NULL,
    [TwoFactorEnabled]     BIT                NOT NULL,
    [UserName]             NVARCHAR (256)     NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_AspNetUsers] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_AspNetUsers_Packages_PackageId] FOREIGN KEY ([PackageId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Packages] ([Id])
);


GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [EmailIndex]
    ON [dbo].[AspNetUsers]([NormalizedEmail] ASC);


GO
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [UserNameIndex]
    ON [dbo].[AspNetUsers]([NormalizedUserName] ASC) WHERE ([NormalizedUserName] IS NOT NULL);


GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_AspNetUsers_PackageId]
    ON [dbo].[AspNetUsers]([PackageId] ASC);
```

Here is my packages code:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Packages] (
    [Id]                INT             IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Cost]              DECIMAL (18, 2) NOT NULL,
    [OrderLimit]        INT             NOT NULL,
    [PackageName]       NVARCHAR (MAX)  NULL,
    [ResetInterval]     INT             NOT NULL,
    [ResetIntervalType] NVARCHAR (MAX)  NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Packages] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);
```

The only connection right now is that User01 in the users table is connected to `packageId` = "1".

Comment: You'd need to show the table schema more than the code. The error is coming from the RDBMS itself rather than c#

Comment: the sql you want is something like: `SELECT p.* FROM AspNetUsers as u WHERE Email = @Email JOIN packages as p ON u.package_id = p.id` This will give you all the package details for the user. As for authentication, I'm not sure. I'd read up/practice a bit on SQL.

Comment: The code you shared doesn't anywhere talk about retrieving `Package` for the user. Can you share that code? And can you tell us what issue you are facing with this code?

Comment: I've updated the question with MySQL code if that helps.

Comment: Based on the database structure it looks like one user can have only one package. Still you didn't share the code which retrieves package information for user and you also didn't tell about the issue you are facing with the current code.

Comment: The current code is all okay I just showed it for reference. I am not facing an issue with the code I have posted I am just in need of a query to solve the issue of retrieving package information from the user.

Comment: The query suggested by MarkJL didn't help ?

Comment: Incorrect syntax near the keyword join.

Answer (score 0):

This query worked and output the correct package.

```
"SELECT p.* FROM AspNetUsers as u JOIN packages as p ON u.package_id = p.id WHERE Email = @Email";
```